# How should I block Google from comment reply URLs?

Tags: seo, nofollow

Users can reply to a comment by clicking on a "reply" link. It just takes the user to a reply box. There will be a reply for every comment any user posts.

For example: if a user clicks on "reply" on a comment with `id=443`, user will be taken to a URL

```
https://example.com/action=reply&replyto=443&onsuccess=https://example.com/news=1
```

It just has a reply box and it has no other content. `onsuccess` is the URL it returns to after reply.

Should I block Google from going to these URLs?

Will `rel="nofollow"` on these reply links help? Or should I make an entry in robots.txt? Is there any alternative method?

I have no issues in search engines indexing these links. But there will be thousands of such links with just a reply box.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can entry comment or reply URLs in robots.txt file.

Note: Google Search Console will index these URLs may be later. You can see these URLs from Google Search Console >> Crawl >> URL Parameters.